# Augmented reality API for IPAD specifically

Tags: ios, ipad, augmented-reality

i'm looking for an AR API (possibly free) or SDK that may be used on IPAD.
I've tried Wikitude so far, but it's not adapted for IPAD for the moment, and most of the well known API seems to be only made for iPhone..
Any clue on this one?

Any chance that this API offer the possibility to add the AR view as a subview (for example as an element of a tab bar..:))

Thanks a lot

Comment: What kind of Augmented Reality are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you going for 3rd party library? You can apply AR using local library. On your `ViewController` make 2 `UIView`. The one in the back implement Camera View on it. And the one on the front implement whatever you want to show on the live preview of camera. Then if you want to capture the screen just simply take a screenshot and it'll be saved.